# SQL Server - How to find a records in INSERTED when the database generates a primary key

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, identity

I've never had to post a question on StackOverflow before because I can always find an answer here by just searching.  Only this time, I think I've got a real stumper....

---

I'm writing code that automates the process of moving data from one SQL Server database to another.  I have some pretty standard SQL Server Databases with foreign key relationships between some of their tables.  Straight forward stuff.  One of my requirements is that the entire table needs to be copied in one fell swoop, without looping through rows or using a cursor.  Another requirement is I have to do this in SQL, no SSIS or other external helpers.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO TargetDatabase.dbo.MasterTable 
SELECT * FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.MasterTable
```

That's easy enough.  Then, once the data from the MasterTable has been moved, I move the data of the child table.

```
INSERT INTO TargetDatabase.dbo.ChildTable 
SELECT * FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.ChildTable
```

Of course, in reality I use more explicit SQL... like I specifically name all the fields and things like that, but this is just a simplified version.  Anyway, so far everything's going alright, except ...

The problem is that the primary key of the master table is defined as an *identity* field.  So, when I insert into the MasterTable, the primary key for the new table gets calculated by the database.  So to deal with that, I tried using the OUTPUT INTO statement to get the updated values into a Temp table:

```
INSERT INTO TargetDatabase.dbo.MasterTable 
OUPUT INSERTED.* INTO @MyTempTable
SELECT * FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.MasterTable
```

So here's where it all falls apart.  Since the database changed the primary key, how on earth do I figure out which record in the temp table matches up with the original record in the source table?

Do you see the problem?  I know what the new ID is, I just don't know how to match it with the original record reliably.  The SQL server lets me output the INSERTED values, but doesn't let me output the FROM TABLE values along side the INSERTED values.  I've tried it with triggers, I've tried it with an SP, always I have the same problem.

If I were just updating one record at a time, I could easily match up my INSERTED values with the original record I was trying to insert to see the old and new primary key values, but I have this requirement to do it in a batch.

Any Ideas?

PS: I'm not allowed to change the table structure of the target or source table.

Comment: Check out SET IDENTITY_INSERT.  You can explicitly set the IDENTITY column values in your initial INSERT of the master table.

Comment: Insert with an order by so you can line up the output.  But if you can't change any table stucture where are you going to save this information anyway?

Comment: Blam, I'm only restricted from change the structure of the target or source table.  I'm using a temp table to store the results.  Are you sure lining up the output will work?  I was under the impression the SQL server does not guarantee order.  So if I insert with an order by, the new identities may still be assigned out of order.

Comment: @Blam, Just checked at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) "When used together with a SELECT...INTO statement to insert rows from another source, the ORDER BY clause does not guarantee the rows are inserted in the specified order."

Comment: Only a comment and then you are kind of boxed in.  In mathematical terms you have more constraints than degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx?ppud=4).

```
declare @Source table (SourceID int identity(1,2), SourceName varchar(50))
declare @Target table (TargetID int identity(2,2), TargetName varchar(50))

insert into @Source values ('Row 1'), ('Row 2')

merge @Target as T
using @Source as S
on 0=1
when not matched then
  insert (TargetName) values (SourceName)
output inserted.TargetID, S.SourceID;
```

Result:

```
TargetID    SourceID
----------- -----------
2           1
4           3
```

Covered in this blog post by Adam Machanic: [Dr. OUTPUT or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the MERGE](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/24/dr-output-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-merge.aspx)

Comment: I had added this suggestion (with the same link) to my answer before seeing this. Then I removed it.  This seems like what the OP wants.

Comment: Perfect!  You get the check.   FYI, as MERGE is a SQL Server 2008 command, I had to check the compatibility level of all my databases first.   Over 600 databases!  I scripted the check using sys.databases though, so no worries.  Another FYI, under stress testing the MERGE command would lock many pages, and sometimes the whole table if copying alot of data.  So I had to update my script to send updates in individual batches of 1000 records if copying data during peak usage times.  Otherwise, normal users would end up waiting way too long for there updates to complete.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate what I mentioned in the comment:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TargetDatabase.dbo.MasterTable  ON

INSERT INTO TargetDatabase.dbo.MasterTable  (IdentityColumn, OtherColumn1, OtherColumn2, ...)
SELECT IdentityColumn, OtherColumn1, OtherColumn2, ... 
FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.MasterTable  

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TargetDatabase.dbo.MasterTable  OFF
```

Okay, since that didn't work for you (pre-existing values in target tables), how about adding a fixed increment (offset) to the id values in both tables (use the current max id value).  Assuming the identity column is "id" in both tables:

```
DECLARE @incr int
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT @incr = max(id)
FROM TargetDatabase.dbo.MasterTable AS m WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TargetDatabase.dbo.MasterTable ON

INSERT INTO TargetDatabase.dbo.MasterTable (id{, othercolumns...})
SELECT id+@incr{, othercolumns...}
FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.MasterTable

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TargetDatabase.dbo.MasterTable OFF

INSERT INTO TargetDatabase.dbo.ChildTable (id{, othercolumns...})
SELECT id+@incr{, othercolumns...} 
FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.ChildTable

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this will work.  I can't insert the identities from SourceDatabase because TargetDatabase may already have some data.  The idea is to let TargetDatabase generate values that are valid in it's table, then find some way to link back to the records in sourceDatabase to figure out what the new value of the primary key is so I can use it in future inserts of related data.